# Compile a java class inside a .war

Tags: java, linux, compilation, wildfly

I have a .war deployed on a Wildfly 12 platform

I modified one class inside this .war in order to be compliant with Linux (replaced backslashes), but now when I try to compile the .java again, I get a lot of errors related to the imports:

```
error: package org.apache.commons.logging does not exist
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
```

I'm compiling from the WEB-INF dir using `javac classes/com/...../test.java`

I tried to include some `-cp` with missing classes, but it does not seem to have any kind of effect.

How should I specify the classpath when compiling a class inside a war? (I don't want to compile the whole package, just one .java to a .class).

Comment: Do you have an access to source code of this .war package? You should modify then files placed there.

Comment: Yes I have, and I modified the .java files. Now I need to re-compile it into a .class. Or should I compile the whole package in one shot?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the dependencies may not be shipped inside the WAR if they can be assumed to come with the application server. You may need to add (some of) wildfly's jars to your classpath.